# "git checkout <another branch>" delete files, how to avoid?

Tags: git

**Environment** :
Two branches `master` and `new_master`.

`.gitignore` file is commited in `master`, it contents

```
...
config/database.yml
...
```

In `new_master` branch, `.gitignore` file is also commited but with different content. it does not contain `config/database.yml`.

**Scenario**:

At branch `new_master`, I change branch to `master`.

```
git checkout master
```

Once I am at branch master, I can't find `config/database.yml` any more. It was there before.

**Question**:

How to avoid delete the file `config/database.yml` when I switch from `new_master` to `master` ?

Comment: How did you “lose it”? Is it committed in the other branch? Not in the other? Is it uncommitted in both? If the first then it’s normal since git will only keep files that are in that branch. If latter, git won’t care about the file unless it conflicts with the other branch

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, database.yml is committed in new_master but not in master.

Comment: We need more information. From where did `new_master` originate? Is the file present in that branch? Did you delete it in either branch? Did you get a merge conflict? Is the file committed to the repository in any of the branches?

Comment: Then it will only exist in the one it’s committed to. If you want it in the other either cherry pick the commit that created it or add it manually

Comment: If you're tracking the file on one branch but not the other, then the behavior of git is to remove the file when you switch branches. That is normal. You can't avoid that, other than to stop tracking the file on either branch, or track it on both.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, new_master is created from master, the file was there. I don't delete anyone in both branch. no confilict.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, You mean I should add it manually every time when I switch from new_master to master ? because this file is ignored in master. I can't commit it.

Comment: No, just once if it can be committed. It can still be added even if it’s ignored. Ignore doesn’t prevent adding, it just tells git not to care about the file in normal situations. If it must not be committed then you need to add it every time.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, Yes, If i can't commit it the file in branch master will be removed every time when I change my branch new_master to master. How to commit a file ignored ? that's the question I should ask. Thank you

Comment: Just use `git add` and if it won’t add then temporarily remove it from ignore, add, commit, put back to ignore. But then the ignore doesn’t do much since it’s already committed and tracked.

Comment: Let's summarize. The file was present in `master`. You created a new branch from it, `new_master`, you did not delete the file in that branch. Later you merged the new branch back into master, now the file is gone. Simply put, this will not happen. There has to be something else here. .gitignore is not used other than with `git add` and only if the file is not already tracked. Somewhere that file has been deleted.

Comment: And no, you do not need to add it every time you switch branches. Simply put, your scenario here is incorrect, you're missing something. If the file **was** in master before you created the new branch, you **did not** delete the file in either branch, you **did not** get a merge conflict, then simply put, the file **will still be there**. So something in this picture is not as you say it is. I still think you have a deletion of that file somewhere.

Comment: Time to brush up on `git bisect`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, Good summarize, So sorry, I did not explain well my situation. Again: The file was present in master. and the file is in .gitignore. I create a new_master from branch master, than I modified .gitignore by removing "config/database.yml". and than I commited config/database.yml in branch new_master. Now I switch branch to master. the file is gone.

Comment: And I'm saying that shouldn't happen. Modifying `.gitignore` should make no difference whatsoever in this case because the file is already tracked. gitignore **does not** impact already tracked files, it only affects `git add <wildcard>` and whether that command picks up **untracked** files or not. If you either forcibly track a file, or the file was already tracked when you added patterns to gitignore that matches, gitignore has no effect on this. **An already tracked file stays tracked until you ask git to untrack the file**, modifying gitignore does not do that.

Comment: If branch A is tracking the file (`git ls-files` lists it) and branch B isn't, checking out A then B then A, and so on, will make the file appear, disappear, appear, etc. The contents of .gitignore on either branch makes no difference in this regard. Basically, the only way you can experience this, since one branch was created from the other, is that one of the branches deleted (untracked) the file. Again, this has nothing to do with gitignore, you need to use `git rm X` or `git add X` (when X has already been deleted on disk) to stage that delete, then commit that.

Comment: So again, you need to find the commit that deletes the file. You have one. I'm 99.9% positive (last 0.1% is "your repository is corrupt" in my opinion)

Comment: Now, let me ask you a control question. You state: "The file was present in master. and the file is in .gitignore." Does this mean A) The file was tracked by master or B) The file existed on disk, but was not tracked or C) I don't understand the difference, or D) I don't know if it's A or B (note, there is nothing wrong or shameful about answering C or D, it just means we need to tackle this problem differently)

Comment: Re-reading this whole thread and your question makes me think the correct reply to that comment of mine is B, let me make another attempt at summarizing what you did. See if it makes sense.

Comment: You had `master`, which had the configuration file in the .gitignore file. The configuration file existed on disk, but due to the gitignore, was not tracked as it had never been added. (this is not, however, the same as "the file was in master", but we can deal with that later). Then you created a new branch, you removed the file from .gitignore, you subsequently *added* the configuration file to the repository (started to track it), committed that. Then you switched back to master, the file disappeared. Is this about right then?

Comment: I'm starting to think that when OP said it was present on `master` and in `.gitignore`, they meant it was in their sandbox with `master` checked out, but not committed in `master` proper, because they said they checked out `new_master`, removed the file from `.gitignore` and committed it. Just a hunch.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, yes, your last hypothesis is totally correct. I was return branch master, I did `git add -f <configuration file>` and I commited it in master. Than the configuration file is tracked in both branch now. So I haven't this problem any more. Thank you for your attention.